# Expected a decleration and missing a (

Tags: function, pow

When I ran this, it gives me the errors you see on the image. Can someone help me on what am I doing wrong here?

```
int n = 2;
int const p = 8;
int e = 1;
int i = 1;

int pow ();
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
        {
            e = i * n;
            if (e == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (e = > 1)
                {
                    cout << e << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

```
E0169 expected a decleration
C2447 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Comment: Is it the semicolon after `int pow () ` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the semicolon after pow() function

it should be

```
int pow ()
{
```

instead of

```
int pow ();
{
```

Comment: But you should always have ; after declerations